# Haskell: Is there a simpler way to express the function (\f g x y -> f (g x) (g y))? Using Applicative ((->) r)?

Tags: haskell, combinators

```
combinator :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
combinator f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

Is there a simpler way to express this function? I find myself using it quite frequently.

I tried using the Applicative instance for (r->) but the best I could get was
`(<*>) : (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b), f <*> g = (\r -> f r (g r))`

Comment: Try [hoogling it](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28b+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+a+-%3E+c&scope=set%3Astackage), and you'll find it's called [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on).

Comment: Note that the definition of `on` is almost exactly your original; it just uses a symbol name `.*.` instead of `f`, and is careful to use an explicit lambda so that `x` and `y` are seen as parameters of the returned function value, instead of parameters of `on` itself (this makes no difference semantically, but can affect things like sharing and inlining; presumably the way it's done in `base` helps performance). If you've got a combinator you find useful frequently, you don't necessarily need a simpler way to express it, just to give it a name so you can reuse it.

Comment: If by "simpler", you mean "point-free", you can eliminate `x` and `y` from the definition by using `Control.Monad.join` and `Data.Bifunctor.bimap`: `combinator f g = curry $ uncurry f . join bimap g`. Eliminating `g` starts getting into partial applications of `(.)`, and eliminating `f` ... *<shudder>*.